# In a table that shows either text or links depending on whether or not a user is logged in to a site, are you able to only hide the text using CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

Currently I'm working on a site where I can only modify the CSS or add some javascript.

If a person were to anonymously (not logged in) view the home page, they would see text that says "You do not have any content saved. Favorite your content to have it display here". However, as soon as that person logs in, they would see a list of links.

In both instances, the content exists in a table. I have been asked to remove the text that displays when a user is not logged in to the site. Is there anyway to do this using CSS or Javascript?

Comment: Do you have any indicator that shows whether the user is logged in?

Comment: There are conditions that I could use like user_is_logged_in, but I could only really use that if I were to build out a plugin for the site. There is nothing specific that I could access on the page.

Comment: check whether any classes get added to the body or html tag once a user is logged in. If they are, you are in business.

Comment: Add an example.